# HBase on Hortonworks HDP Sandbox: Can't get master address from ZooKeeper

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper, hortonworks-data-platform

I downloaded HDP 2.1 from hortonworks for virtualbox. I got the following error when using Hbase shell in case simple command: create 't1', {NAME=> 'f1', VERSIONS => 5}

Hortonworks “ERROR: Can't get master address from ZooKeeper; znode data == null”

What do I need to do to get hbase working in this sandbox environment?

Answer (score 4):

In hortonwork sandbox you have to manually start hbase.

Try to run the following command (as root user),

```
su hbase - -c "/usr/lib/hbase/bin/hbase-daemon.sh --config /etc/hbase/conf start master; sleep 20"

su hbase - -c "/usr/lib/hbase/bin/hbase-daemon.sh --config /etc/hbase/conf start regionserver"
```

then run "jps" (as root user too).

if you see "HMaster" and "HRegionServer", your hbase is now on.

"hbase shell" again to see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you did not start or even configured HBase in the VM. go into the ambari management console and install/activate HBase

Comment: Ambari was not started by default on my virtual machine (virtualbox, HDP 2.1). SSH into the sandbox and execute: ambari-server start   Then you can log in to ambari by visiiting http://127.0.0.1:8080 and use admin/admin for the username password the first time.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same problem in my system:

Root cause: its due to when creating table its point to HDFS namenode (**port 9000**) Connection refused problem

I just formatted the namenode also check connectivity to **port 9000** (but its not good in production real time)

```
$hadoop namenode format
```

after that `#start-all.sh`

```
$(HBASE_HOME)/bin/start-hbase.sh
```

Start habse shell

Problem will resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue, solved by restarting HBase server manually from the browser.

Answer (score 0):

in my case,I forget to start ZooKeeper first,

`./zkServer.sh start`

so I start the ZooKeeper  and then restart the hbase:

`./stop-hbase.sh`

`./start-hbase.sh`