# Hbase on a VM: Can not access zookeeper after coming out of sleep on a laptop

Tags: hbase, virtual-machine, apache-zookeeper, hibernation

The following error occurs on a VM **after bringing the laptop out of sleep or hiberation**

> ERROR: Can't get master address from ZooKeeper; znode data == null

This error occurs when running any simple command from the hbase shell, for example:

```
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/etc/hbase/conf.dist $hbase shell
Version 0.96.1.1-cdh5.0.0, rUnknown, Thu Mar 27 23:03:17 PDT 2014

hbase(main):001:0> list
TABLE                                                                                                                     

ERROR: Can't get master address from ZooKeeper; znode data == null
```

Has anyone worked with HBase on a VM and a laptop, or have any insight on what is happening and how to handle this?

Note: please do not flag as DUPLICATE.  Yes, there are two other related questions.

But: the answer to the first one does not apply to my situation - since the settings are for standalone alrady in my case:

> [get "ERROR: Can't get master address from ZooKeeper; znode data == null" when using Hbase shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22663484/get-error-cant-get-master-address-from-zookeeper-znode-data-null-when-us)

The second one never received any answer (possibly due to the questionable formatting/wording):

> [HBase on Hortonworks HDP Sandbox: Can't get master address from ZooKeeper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24207493/hortonworks-error-cant-get-master-address-from-zookeeper-znode-data-null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I will just need to live with this. The fastest workaround is to restart zookeeper. That is actually not so bad - at least not as painful as restarting all of HBase.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Besides just restarting zookeeper? No - that is what I would do.  But I have not seen the behavior for some time. Which version of hbase are you using? I was on approximately  0.94 at the time

Comment: Still on 0.98.11. It would be nice to know a newer version does not exhibit this behavior, but could not confirm from searching the net